# Sharing code between two GCP python Cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two different GCP cloud functions coded in python that would benefit from sharing part of the code, is there any way to reference common code between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Artifact Registry to host your own and private pipy](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/quickstart) registry. Deploy your common code in this registry and use it in your functions dependencies definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried by myself, but based on documentation, that may be the only feasible way:

[Using private dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies)

Another hypothetical option is to use `pip`:

[Specifying dependencies with pip](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#specifying_dependencies_with_pip)

but I am not sure that you are ready for such path...