# How to share similar code between Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, code-duplication

I have multiple Cloud Functions in Google Cloud Platform that are very similar, changing only a few parameters and variable values ​​between them.

Is there a way to tackle this problem, organizing them like Python modules in order to reduce code duplication? Sharing the same variable and functions between them, maybe?

I've thought about using [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var) but they do not offer the purpose that I want.

And none of this other two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136369/how-to-share-code-between-client-and-cloud-functions)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202735/sharing-code-between-two-gcp-python-cloud-functions)  have any guidance on that.

Comment: If the code is the same and can be parameterized, Env Vars are the right solution. if it's more a package, a libraries, that you use as base of your development, and slightly adapt it for each function, you must package your code in a module, deploy it on Artifact Registry and reference it in you r requirements.txt file. https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere

> If the code is the same and can be parameterized, Env Vars are the right solution. if it's more a package, a libraries, that you use as base of your development, and slightly adapt it for each function, you must package your code in a module, deploy it on Artifact Registry and reference it in you r requirements.txt file. [cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python)